# group timestamp in message box like facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have a div fetch out all conversation between user

```
while{
 $name
 $message;
 $time
}
```

How to group the same date messages together like facebook.

I try

```
if($data['time']<($time()-(60*60*24))){echo $date."<hr>";}
```

inside while loop, but I don't want it keep echo under every message

I need it display like this

```
22/7/2013---------------------
ben:lol             02:30 pm
alex: ya I know     02.31 pm

23/7/2013----------------------
ben:hey how are u    01:40 pm
alex: good           01.45 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the standard date value using `gmdate("Y-m-d", $data['created_time'])` and then group the messages using it.